# Theme displays on localhost and not on domain server, please help!

Tags: magento2, php, error, theme

For some odd reason my theme is not displaying on the live server but on the localhost it shows perfectly fine. What could be the cause of this issue?

Thanks in advance!

[image: This is on the domain]

[image: This is local]

Comment: can you run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** in live and see if it is fixed ?

Comment: What do you have for web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url in core_config_data?

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli i did that and get this error message " NOTE: Manual static content deployment is not required in "default" and "developer" modes." i also tried -f at the end of that command. It runs, but nothing comes of it after it runs.

Comment: Do you have any additional cache that forget to clean?

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli all caches were cleaned accordingly. I still cant find what the issue is. The theme is still not loading! :(

Comment: @Mike i actually can't seem to find that file path within the directory.

Comment: @grdevco can you check network tab of your web developer toolbar and see what request are getting sent for CSS and JS

Comment: @AtishGoswami Hello, these are some of the errors i am currently getting. 

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
brand.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
americanexpress.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
discover.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of`

Comment: @grdevco can you check the var/log/expection.log to see the exact error that is happening on the server ?

Comment: @AtishGoswami `[2018-10-25 01:35:54] main.CRITICAL: No host configured to connect {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(code: 0): No host configured to connect at /home/public_html/grwebdev/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:377)"} []` 

The error above is the one i'm currently seeing repeatedly in exception.log.

Comment: @AtishGoswami I'm also getting the following error. 

`[2018-10-25 02:05:02] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES) {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(code: 1045)`

Comment: @grdevco seems that the application is not able to connect to the database can you check the app/etc/env.php file and see if the database connectivity credentials are proper

Comment: @AtishGoswami Would I have to add a user to the to the database I imported? I think that may be the issue at hand. I created a database in CPanel and maybe those credentials would have to be added to the 'admin_user' table on the imported database.

Answer (score 0):

Enter in your database and run this query

> SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'web/';

, make sure it is all set up correctly . 
What change did you made before the frontend broke ?How do you make deploys in live site ? 
Run everything you can :

- rm -r pub/static/*
- rm -r generated/*
- rm -r var/cache/*
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- sudo service varnish restart (if you have varnish in your site)
- Clear CDN (if you have setup cdn)
- run a git status in your repo, to see for any change in root.
- sudo service php-fpm restart.

Answer (score 0):

Give the permissions under root folder var/ pub/

sudo chmod 777 -R var/ pub/

After permission clear folder

1. var/cache, var/generation, var/view_proceed.
2. pub/static/frontend.

then refresh your site.